# I want to hide tables in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, azure

I've created a data sync process in Azure so that Azure has created few tables in my SQL Server database in the `Datasync` schema. I want to hide those tables that are located in the `Datasync` schema.

Can you guys please suggest how to avoid showing those tables in Azure, or how to hide tables from my SQL Server?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "hide"? You can't hide objects in SQL Server like you can in a file system.

Comment: I mean invisible for some users

Comment: You can't. You could `DENY` them access to do anything with them, such as `SELECT` `ALTER` and even view the definition, or ensure you don't `GRANT` them any permissions on the `DataSync` schema, but you can't stop a user in a database from being able to see the objects in it.

Comment: >>>but you can't stop a user in a database from being able to see the objects in it<<< User without any permission or with DENY on some table DOES NOT see this table in OE

Comment: @sepupic OE? hazarding a guess here; Oracle Enterprise? What does that have to do with the SQL Server on Azure? Oracle and SQL Server are 2 completely different products. That's like saying "I can do this on Windows, but I can't on a Ubuntu. Why not?" Because they're different. They're both Operating Systems (or database engines), but theya re not one and the same.

Comment: @Larnu, OE is also the SSMS Object Explorer. Meta-data visibility is controlled by permissions so a user must have some permissions to see the table.

Comment: @NimeshGami, what permissions were granted that allow the users to see the tables? Objects are not visible unless permissions were granted or via role membership.

Comment: @ Larnu OE = Object Explorer. That SSMS window that shows you a "tree" of database objects is called Object Explorer

Comment: >>>Objects are not visible unless permissions were granted or via role membership.<<< That is what I was talking about.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d1c648cf-9831-443f-82f9-3059bdff2751/how-to-hide-tables-in-ssms-to-a-particular-user-but-they-can-still-can-select-the-table?forum=sqlsecurity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is No `HIDE` feature in SQL Server instead, you can Deny the permission to that Table for Certain Users of User Groups whom you do not want to view the Tables or Objects on your schema

You can Use the `DENY` keyword to deny certain Users and `REVOKE` to Remove the existing permission

Answer (score 7):

This question is somewhat old, but today I was looking for something similar so that I can organize tables in my database, either by hiding tables whose designing is completed, or placing them in some folder so that they do not interfere with the tables that I am currently working on *(and confuse me :P )*.

I found this article which discusses [Hiding tables in SSMS Object Explorer](https://sqlstudies.com/2017/04/03/hiding-tables-in-ssms-object-explorer-using-extended-properties/)

Using extended properties, the OP was able to hide tables from the view.
You can read in more details in the article itself, but for this answer purpose, I am reproducing the OP's code here

**Hide Table "Person.Address"**

```
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty
@name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support',
@value = 'Hide',
@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = 'Person',
@level1type = N'Table', @level1name = 'Address';
GO
```

**Show Table "Person.Address"**

```
EXEC sp_dropextendedproperty
@name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support',
@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = 'Person',
@level1type = N'Table', @level1name = 'Address';
GO
```

---

I have just used this on one of my table `dbo.Users.Logins`, for that I had used

`@level0name='dbo'`, and

`@level1name='Users.Logins'`

After executing the command, I refreshed the tables list, it took some 45 seconds to refresh (not sure it is usual or not) but after refresh **the specified table's name was NOT in the list of tables**

After removing the extended property, the table's name **was back again**.

---

Even when hidden, the table was working properly (`SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` and `JOINS`)

---

I am using SQL Server Management Studio v18.4 (© 2019)

HTH.

Comment: Additional article [Hidden tables in SSMS: detect and create them!](https://www.sqlserverscience.com/internals/tables-hidden-ssms/)